# On start debug app MAUI template project error

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, maui

I created default template project, my goal is migration xamarin.forms to MAUI and before start I tried test it.

If I use IOS it is work fine, no problem, but if it is android I get error
[image]

Package name on screenshot is directly package name app.

App installs and builds, I can start it on android device but I cant debug it.

I did in template code nothing, and it is reason why I don't add it in question.

I don't understand what I need do.

Comment: Is DriverHelper v2.0 a third party plugin? And do you mean a default xamarin project cannot deploy to an android device?

Comment: @LiqunShen-MSFT default MAUI project, I mean projct which creates within new solution and has some minimum functions. DriverHelper v2.0 is name this project.

Comment: Does it work on an android emulator?

Comment: @LiqunShen-MSFT I tried physical and emulator result is same

Comment: Thanks for your response. Right now I cannot reproduce the issue. You know I have created a new solution with the default maui template and named it DriverHelper v 2.0. But it can successfully deploy to an android emulator.

Comment: Then I notice that you also add some minimum functions right? So I wonder if this issue is related to these minimum functions. Can you elaborate more on these functions?

Comment: By the way, do you use Visual Studio 2022? And what's the .NET version and Android API version?

Comment: @LiqunShen-MSFT when I added package="com.companyname.driverhelper_v_2.x_0" android:installLocation="internalOnly" to manifest, this problem is gone. Thank you very much

Comment: So glad you solve it! though I don't understand why it works. Feel free to post an answer below, which could help others with similar questions! Thanks for your sharing!